# Python Class method hooks and derivation

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import unittest


class MyBaseThingTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Abstract
    """

    def setUp(self):
        # Is a hook in unittest.TestCase
        self.x = 1

    def tearDown(self):
        # Is a hook in unittest.TestCase
        self.x = 0


class MyThingTestClass(MyBaseThingTestClass):
    """
    Real Test
    """

    def setUp(self):
        print('I do what I want')
        super(MyThingTestClass, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        print('Im done')
        super(MyThingTestClass, self).tearDown()

    def test_x(self):
        assert self.x == 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The methods setUp and tearDown of unittest.TestCase are Hooks, so no implementation and we don't need to call super in MyBaseThingTestClass:

```
def setUp(self):
    "Hook method for setting up the test fixture before exercising it."
    pass

def tearDown(self):
    "Hook method for deconstructing the test fixture after testing it."
    pass
```

My question is: Is it possible to develop a two level derivation like I did, without needing to call super in the MyThingTestClass for setUp and tearDown methods?
The only way I see is to create two methods with other names, so MyThingTestClass should override them and not the default ones. But I don't want that because everybody knows the names and wants to use them.

Thanks

Comment: It’s unclear what you mean. btw did you mean super().setUp()?

Comment: @quamrana, yes, thats what I mean.